# How to set metadata in TypeScript / Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I create an actionConfig.ts where I create a constant `ACTIONS` so I can use them in my components.

At the moment I have Edit and Delete.

Now I have to create another constant that I call `METADATA` because I need it in a different place.

```
export const ACTIONS = [
  {
    label: 'Delete',
    actionType: 'DELETE',
    deleteApi: 'api/USERS'/* url dell api di delete /backend) */
  },
  {
    label: 'Edit',
    actionType: 'GO_TO',
    getUrl: row => '/detail/' + row.id,
  },
];

export const METADATA = {
  add:
    {
      label: 'Add',
      actionType: 'GO_TO',
      getUrl: '/detail/-1',
    },
};
```

In my component.ts I added the method `getMetadata` as I did for the Actions.

```
 getMetadata(): void {
   this.metadata = this.userService.getMetadata();
 }
```

I get an error in `this.metadata` that says

> TS2740: Type '{ add: { label: string; actionType: string; getUrl: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more

so I think that my configuration isn't right...

What do I have to do?

Comment: How this `metadata` and `getMetadata` variable/ function looks like

Comment: metadata = []; then i set it inside ngOnInit() and then I created getMetada()

Comment: Your `METADATA` constant is an object, not an array, but you've typed it as `any[]`. Type it as `any` (or better yet, an actual type).

Comment: @HereticMonkey where exactly? metadata = any; ?

Comment: `this.metatdata = [];` implicitly types `this.metadata` as `any[]`.